# Is this system of equations solvable?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have derived a handful of equations to describe how it may be possible to find the angle of a rectangle inscribed inside of another rectangle in two different states. The equations I have come up with are as follows:
$$
h_1 = X\sin(\theta) + Y\cos(\theta)\\
w_1 = Y\sin(\theta) + X\cos(\theta)\\
h_2 = X\sin(\theta + \gamma) + Y\cos(\theta + \gamma)\\
w_2 = Y\sin(\theta + \gamma) + X\cos(\theta + \gamma)\\
$$
where $h_1$, $w_1$, $h_2$, $w_2$, and $\gamma$ are all known.

I was under the assumption that, since I only had three unknowns ($X$, $Y$, and $\theta$), and four equations, that I should have more than enough information to solve the system. However, I have since become tied up in a mess of trig functions.

Is this system just difficult to solve, or is it impossible? Is there a way I can test the solvability of the system?

Comment: You have too many equations: usually there will be no solution for arbitrary $h_1$, $w_1$, $h_2$, $w_2$, $\gamma$

Comment: Have a look at the edit. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to eliminate $X$ and $Y$ using the first and the second equations and obtain
$$X=\sec (2 \theta )\left(w_1 \cos (\theta )-h_1 \sin (\theta )\right)\qquad \qquad Y=\sec (2 \theta )\left(h_1 \cos (\theta )-w_1 \sin (\theta )\right)$$
So the third equation is
$$\sec (2 \theta ) (h_1 \cos (\gamma +2 \theta )+w_1 \sin (\gamma ))-h_2=0\tag3$$ and the fourth is
$$\sec (2 \theta ) (w_1 \cos (\gamma +2 \theta )+h_1 \sin (\gamma ))-w_2=0\tag4$$ If the system is consistant, just write
$$\frac {h_1 \cos (\gamma +2 \theta )+w_1 \sin (\gamma ) } {w_1 \cos (\gamma +2 \theta )+h_1 \sin (\gamma ) }=\frac {h_2}{w_2}\tag 5$$ which looks simple.

Let $t=\gamma +2 \theta $ and obtain
$$t=\pm \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (\gamma ) (w_1 w_2-h_1 h_2)}{h_2 w_1-h_1
   w_2}\right) \implies \theta=\frac {t-\gamma} 2$$

If the system is not consistent, this is another story (to be discussed).

**Edit**

The system could be "close" to consistency but not consistent (say because of numerical inaccuracies). So, let us try to solve it as a data reconciation problem. To give the same weight to each equation, consider the objective function
$$\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^4 \Bigg[\frac{\text{rhs}_i-\text{lhs}_i}{\text{lhs}_i }\Bigg]^2$$ to be minimized with respect to $(X,Y,\theta)$. Computing the three partial derivatives and setting them equal to $0$ gives three equations
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial X}=0\qquad \qquad\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial Y}=0 \qquad \qquad\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta}=0$$ The first and second are linear in $(X,Y)$ which means the we have the ("super" nasty) expressions $X(\theta)$ and  $Y(\theta)$. Plugging them in the third partial derivative leads to a monstreous equation in  $\theta$. No hope to have anything analytical.

So, to check if the system is or not consistent, use the first part of this answer and compute $\Phi$; if it is $0$, the system was consistent. If not zero, solve the monster.

For illustration purposes, using $h_1=232$, $w_1=261$, $h_2=165$, $w_2=256$ and $\gamma=\frac \pi 8$, the first procedure gives
$$\theta=0.945254\quad \qquad X=112.139\quad \qquad Y=240.966\quad \qquad \Phi=8.40\times 10^{-4}$$
while the data were generated using
$$\theta=1.000000\quad \qquad X=123.000\quad \qquad Y=234.000$$

Using the second step
$$\theta=0.978107\quad \qquad X=117.412\quad \qquad Y=236.720\quad \qquad \Phi=1.44\times 10^{-4}$$ which is much better.

The first step is very useful since it provides the $\theta_0$ to start the Newton method for the second step. For the worked example, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 0.9452538356 \\
 1 & 0.9761775003 \\
 2 & 0.9781025866 \\
 3 & 0.9781070754
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Oh I was so close! That trick you did in equation 5 is what I was missing. Formally, how would I know if the system is consistent? (Intuitively I think it's consistent because the inscribed rectangle has the same dimensions for each state, but I don't know how to prove it)